# MVC parsing the wrong view layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I've come across a little oddity, where on my development machine, everything works fine, but on my server, it does not.

```
public static string RenderViewToString(this Controller controller, string viewName, object model, string masterName)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
        viewName = controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

    controller.ViewData.Model = model;

    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName, masterName);
        ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

Using the above code, I am rendering a View to a string, which is then sent via email.

[image: File layout]

As you can see from the file list above, I have an Emails folder that contains a number of views and a _ViewStart.cshtml file.

The NewUser.cshtml sets **@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_email.cshtml" }** (_email.cshtml has Layout = "" in the head) as well as uses the _ViewStart.cshtml to define the "master page" for the view.

Now... On my production server, when I try and render the NewUser.cshtml, it throws an error stating that it is missing a required section that is declared within the _public.cshtml layout.

On my development machine (using VS2010's built in server) - it works...

Any idea's?

Cheers

Comment: Probably not the issue, but typically you'd set `Layout` in `_viewstart`, not in the individual views.

Comment: Thanks David. When creating the views, it asks which "master" view I would like to use. I simply select the "_email.cshtml" file and it pre-populates this for me.

Comment: There's actually a comment under the "Use a layout or master page" field that says "Leave empty if it is set in a Razor _viewstart file. It's subtle, and something that won't keep your app from working, but it's nice to be able to set the master/layout in a single file instead of in every view.